# fetch Data into angular2 form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-forms

i am trying to fetch users data back into form but i am unable to do so,
please help me,
here is my code.

i want to get the data loaded into the edit form on OnInit(), i am using angular 4 , and backend is .Net MVC,
and also explain what's wrong in my code.

code for list component
enter code here

```
`<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Contact ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone </th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
            <td>{{ contact.ContactID }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.FirstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.LastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.Phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.Email }}</td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/contactedit', contact.ContactID]">Edit</a>
            <!-- <td><a (click) = "onEdit( contact.ContactID )" class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</a> </td> -->
            <td><a (click) = "onDelete( contact.ContactID)" class="btn btn-primary" >Delete</a></td>

        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`
```

here is the html of edit form component

```
`<form
    [formGroup] = "form"
  (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(form.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="FirstName" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="FirstName">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName" placeholder="Password" formControlName="LastName">
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Phone"  placeholder="Password" formControlName="Phone">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Password" formControlName="Email" >

  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">Update</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
</form>`
```

here is the code of edit form component.ts

```
`import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Contact } from './contact.interface';

import { ActivatedRoute , Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MediaService } from './media.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchmap';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-media-form',
    //moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'app/media-form.component.html'
})
export class MediaFormEditComponent implements OnInit {
     id: string;
    currentContact: Contact;
    contactForm: FormGroup;
    private sub: any;
    form;
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private route : ActivatedRoute,
            private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private mediaService: MediaService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        debugger;
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            FirstName: this.formBuilder.control('',Validators.required),
            LastName: this.formBuilder.control('',Validators.required),
            Email: this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
            Phone: this.formBuilder.control('',Validators.required)    
        });
        this.sub = this.route.params
        .map(params => params['id'])
        .switchMap(id => this.mediaService.getContactById(id))
            .subscribe((cont: Contact) => {
                this.currentContact = cont;

                this.contactForm.setValue({
                    FirstName      : cont.FirstName,
                    LastName: cont.LastName,
                    Email: cont.Email,
                    Phone: cont.Phone
                });
            });
    }

    onSubmit(Data){
        this.mediaService.UpdateContact(Data)
        .subscribe(data => this.router.navigate(['contacts']));
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an array before your loop (after fetch data):

```
let newFormArray: FormGroup[] = [];
```

In your loop:

```
 newFormArray.push(this.fb.group({ FirstName: [cont[i].FirstName, Validators.required], LastName: [cont[i].LastName, Validators.required] //... 
}));
```

Then make your form:

```
        this.form = this.fb.group({
        array: this.fb.array(newFormArray)
    })
```

Imports: `import { FormControl, FormArray, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working, can you post a specific answer,